# Manually add folder to unity game apk before shipping

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, filesystems

My game needs to have a folder with a few files in the games data directory (ie Android/Data/com.application.name/needed_folder/needed_file), is there anyways i can add them directly into the apk with android studio and have them in the folder?

Ive tired just putting it in the assets folder but they didn't get moved and caused some wack issues with unity

Comment: No, if they don’t exist, you need to create or copy them at runtime by code into the app data folder, which is for persisted user data not for app data, which is a bit of confusing naming. Why do you need those files there?

Comment: There is a "Resources" folder that is persisted when building an application.  I've used it to load various kinds of data (including text files).  This may or may not be applicable for you. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html